# Test purchases not showing up in Google Wallet Merchant

Tags: android, payment, billing, in-app

I'm setting up and testing In-app Purchases for android. I was able to make a test purchase. However, I can not find a way to delete that order to keep on testing. According to [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#testing-purchases) article, I should be able to cancel it: Cancel purchases manually—you can go to the Google payments merchant center, look up the transaction, and then cancel it. You can find transactions by looking up their order numbers.

But my Payments Merchant center has no transactions on it and I'm using my own product ID's and not the product IDs for static responses. Help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cancelling orders on Google Play IAB test purchases after June 20, 2016](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130035/cancelling-orders-on-google-play-iab-test-purchases-after-june-20-2016)

Answer (score 4):

I was experiencing the same problem and contacted Google Play support and received the following answer:

> Beginning June 20, 2016, we changed test purchases for one-time in-app
>   purchases (IAPs).
>
> Previously, test purchases for one-time IAPs generated order IDs.
>   Starting June 20, 2016, one-time IAPs do not generate order IDs and
>   will not appear in the Merchant Center. This behavior already applies
>   to subscription IAPs.
>
> You can learn more about testing in-app billing in the Android
>   Developers Help Center:
>   https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#testing-purchases

Receipts for the test payments are still getting sent to the test account emails so it may be worth checking for these to see whether the test payments are going through. I am currently not sure how to cancel test purchases however.

Comment: If you figure out how to cancel the test purchases please answer the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130035/cancelling-orders-on-google-play-iab-test-purchases-after-june-20-2016

Comment: @IwoBanas Antonio has updated their question on the link you gave to add the official answer from Google Support that the Play Developer Console doesn't currently support cancellation of test IAP. The only ways is to either consume the IAP or wait the 14 days consumption time.

Answer (score 0):

It may take a while to show transactions on Merchant account,also mention if your purchase is subscription or managed coz if it is managed product you need to consume the product before you purchase  again and you cannot purchase again if its  subscription refer:http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consume