# How can I cancel?

Tags: java, android, database, testing, in-app-purchase

I have been testing in app billing on android with a test account, but after making my first test purchase, I want to cancel it and test again. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html):

> **Canceling completed test purchases**
>
> Google Play accumulates completed
> test purchases for each user but does not pass them on to financial
> processing.
>
> In some cases, you might want to manually cancel a test purchase to
> continue testing. To do so, open the app page in the Play Store.
>
> Important: The refund() and revoke() methods of the
> Purchases.subscriptions API don't support test purchases.

The documentation says to just open the app page in the play store...but there are no options to cancel test purchases on the app page...

Also, I can't use `refund()` or `revoke()` to cancel it programmatically, so I'm stuck with trying to figure out how to do this manually. **How can I cancel my test purchase?**

Thanks,

Ruchir

EDIT: Note this is **NOT** a subscription, but a regular item purchase, which is why I cannot use the `cancel()` method.

Comment: The following link would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130035/cancelling-orders-on-google-play-iab-test-purchases-after-june-20-2016

Answer (score -2):

same documentation says

In some cases, you might want to manually cancel a test purchase to continue testing. To do so, open the app page in the Play Store. If the test purchase that you want to cancel is a subscription, you can also use the cancel() method of the Purchases.subscriptions API.

So you can use cancel() method.

Comment: It is not a subscription, which is why I did not include that portion of the quoted documentation. I cannot use the `cancel()` method unless I am dealing with a subscription, which I am not.